# Client certificate selection

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a https apache server that needs client verification. But when somebody is browsing this site there is need to select proper cert from list of certificates installed in browsers. What can I do to become client cert default to my webpage (so clients do no need to select cert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your certificate valid and signed by a 3rd party root authority like `Thawte, Verisign`... etc?

Comment: That is your problem, browsers won't accept your `self-signed` certificate unless users manually install the certificate in their systems.

Comment: but I'm generating new cert for each client and I'm sending it to him. So I must have trusted CA?

Comment: Yes those certificates are insecure because they are not signed by a root CA. Browsers _must_ show a dialog for those since it can't be trusted.

Comment: And please tell me how browser will recognize what to select if I will provide  valid not self-signed cert.

Comment: By the way, I have added to trusted my self-signed root cert on the browser. Now I also must select proper cert. I dont think it is about trust, but about some association with server name or dns

Comment: if you certificate & hostname doesn't match it won't pass either.

Comment: which values should be the same? certificate CN and ServerName?

Comment: CN should match the host name.

Comment: only in client cert or also in cert that signs client cert?

Comment: Client cert should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control from the server which client certificate is presented - you can only indicate that you expect a clientside certificate (SSLVerifyClient). Most browsers allow the user to associate websites with individual client certs. There is no way to manipulate this from the serverside.

Comment: but i'm providing client particural p12 file which he should use. When I'm using CN=properhostname it's ok on firefox (it selects it automatically) but not on safari

Comment: WTF? CN=properhostname looks like a SERVER certificate - not a CLIENT certificate. What has that got to do with client verification?

Comment: so  there is no any way to associate them automatically?